# How to get a specific value from a html header

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests, header

Im using selenium to get request headers from a web page,
the problem is that it prints out all request headers sent and i want to get only one value from one of them. I dont know how to do it and i havent found anything on the internet, I used this line of code to get the request headers ```

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
for req in driver.requests:
    print(req.headers)
```

and this is ex. what the console prints out

```
/Users/andrew/Downloads/andrewtate/respon.py:8: DeprecationWarning: find_element_by_* commands are deprecated. Please use find_element() instead
  element = driver.find_element_by_id("liveSwitch")
content-length: 537
x-ms-apiversion: 2
uaid: 4276e35e10994d41a4f8b9d772597415
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36
canary: ZsWLDeZFgz9FMStm3ag92konX3u1nFMb5JrOsAmAVOXif1MhviASbSrIbTSEBeVN3swoIqb9Nxrhv29kmwRlAreLZxaTbyMXlhcBjeXQL/xXtNVRAHzRRn841XYbOsaAnTtD+m/+0eseb0AOal3OUUrXRuCNiMQTfWV94E4rG3wbhVc+wOFKr6CJdRbdnHCJJ+KKCCyD6Zi5iiyYy/WDeOpiRm4bGTJfxovswmLBI+vSh8+8gmclbitKCSQ9WNCi:2:3c
content-type: application/json
hpgid: 200639
accept: application/json
tcxt: 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:2:3
uiflvr: 1001
scid: 100118
sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"
x-ms-apitransport: xhr
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
origin: https://signup.live.com
sec-fetch-site: same-origin
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-dest: empty
referer: https://signup.live.com/signup?lic=1&uaid=4276e35e10994d41a4f8b9d772597415
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: amsc=b55INNzzHR5PZiPunWJJsx3fMAbVhvWRQlJkJfRh2zNI+jGPtSvnOYjXiJqnEctddyQyWNV64rFgnX9Qf57EA+YiA/VCFcqp6ogo+iXCvLBLpDne1H1QImvS5lgln9YT1eI5JbSQYm789c/XXcVi3mCEE9vKzuLq4CovhNTdvcBk/hXxtcDePtoNIZOjrfUSfP4/Gp34hMJFNK79iAo2rhl/WK9jO894h00DrAKnMEiA4Cd57LVili0DAOXInzcFSQ7TjRXBpNr2KoO2RB1ARd9sjjaQfycR/n6r6P5Fj+o=:2:3c


sec-ch-ua: "Chromium";v="104", " Not A;Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="104"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "macOS"
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
sec-fetch-site: same-site
sec-fetch-mode: navigate
sec-fetch-dest: iframe
referer: https://signup.live.com/
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
cookie: amsc=b55INNzzHR5PZiPunWJJsx3fMAbVhvWRQlJkJfRh2zNI+jGPtSvnOYjXiJqnEctddyQyWNV64rFgnX9Qf57EA+YiA/VCFcqp6ogo+iXCvLBLpDne1H1QImvS5lgln9YT1eI5JbSQYm789c/XXcVi3mCEE9vKzuLq4CovhNTdvcBk/hXxtcDePtoNIZOjrfUSfP4/Gp34hMJFNK79iAo2rhl/WK9jO894h00DrAKnMEiA4Cd57LVili0DAOXInzcFSQ7TjRXBpNr2KoO2RB1ARd9sjjaQfycR/n6r6P5Fj+o=:2:3c
```

I only want to get `canary:` value and put it to request headers so when i do `print(requestToWebsite.request.headers)` i can see the value

Any help would be appreciated,
Thank you.

Comment: The code shown will not produce that output. Please clarify

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

driverReq=str(driver.requests);

ans= re.search('canary:(.*)content-type:', driverReq)
print(ans.group(1))
```