# Cant replace spaces in a python variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, http, replace, header

i tried to replace spaces in a variable in python but it returns me this error

```
AttributeError: 'HTTPHeaders' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

this is my code

```
for req in driver.requests:
    print(req.headers)
    d = req.headers    


x = d.replace("""
""", "")
```

Comment: *d* refers to an HTTPHeaders class. *replace()* is a built-in function for *str* classes

Comment: You can only call `replace` on a string object. Clearly, `d` is not that but it's an `HTTPHeaders` object.

Comment: @MichelKok *replace()* is not necessarily limited to *str* classes. Any class could implement a *replace()* function

Comment: @Stuart then how can i make it so it would be a ```str``` class and it would work? ```str(d)```?

Comment: Can you provide some more code @iluvpython12341? E.g., what is HTTPHeaders exactly?

Comment: @iluvpython12341 You haven't shown enough code for us to be sure where the HTTPHeaders class is coming from. What does the output from *print(req.headers)* look like. That will tell you what the class's *str* or *repr* implementations are doing

Comment: @Stuart I’m not at home right now, but the output is request headers of 4-5 requests with 2 new lines in between each other, i will provide better output when i will be at home.

Comment: @Stuart https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73359667/how-to-get-a-specific-value-from-a-html-header this is ex. of output i received. I want to get the canary value out of it so i want to delete the new lines in between requests transform all of it to json string and then get the value out

Comment: @MichelKok^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you check out the class [`HTTPHeaders`](https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire/blob/9368006c5e2636efb816b3eb345dc60ac8bfb43d/seleniumwire/request.py#L9) you'll see it has a `__repr__` function and that it's an [HTTPMessage](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html#httpmessage-objects) object.

Depending on what you exactly want to achieve (which is still not clear to me!, i.e, for which header do you want to replace spaces?) you can go about this two ways. Use the methods on the HTTPMessage object (documented [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.compat32-message.html#email.message.Message)) or use the string version of it by calling `repr` on the response. I recommend you use the first approach as it is much cleaner.

I'll give an example in which I remove spaces for all canary values in all of the requests:

```
for req in driver.requests:
    canary = req.headers.get("canary")
    canary = canary.replace(" ", "")
```

P.S., your question is nowhere near clear enough as it stands. Only after asking multiple times and linking your other question it becomes clear that you are using `seleniumwire`, for example. Ideally, the code you provide can be run by anyone with the installed packages and reproduces the issue you have. BUT, allright, the comments made it more clear.

Comment: I want to get the canary value of request headers here is the full code ```from seleniumwire import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://signup.live.com/signup")
element = driver.find_element_by_id("liveSwitch")
element.click()  
s = requests.Session()
for req in driver.requests:
    print(req.headers)
```

Comment: Did you try my example code?

Comment: However it print outs "None" until it finds the data and when i did ```headers = {"canary": canary}``` and then make ```r = requests.post('website.com', headers=headers) print(r.request.headers) ``` it doesnt show the canary value there.